# Have two timepickers on same HTML/Angular Page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-moment

I am currently using angular-moment-picker (https://github.com/indrimuska/angular-moment-picker) library and it works great! However, I have a silly question that I am struggling with. I am using the timepicker from this library and when I added a second one any changes i make on the first time picker they are automatically added on the second one. Any ideas? Thank you in advance!!

HTML:

```
<md-input-container>
                        <input class="form-control"
                            moment-picker="ctrl.timepicker"
                            format="hh:mm A"
                            show-header="false"
                            ng-model="test.startTime"
                            ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                            ng-required="true">
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container>
                        <input class="form-control"
                            moment-picker="ctrl.timepicker"
                            format="hh:mm A"
                            show-header="false"
                            ng-model="test.endTime"
                            ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
                            ng-required="true">
                    </md-input-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used this library, but I suspect the problem is that both time-pickers have the same object set as their `moment-picker`.  On the docs it calls this a two-way bindable property so when you change it from one timepicker it overwrites the other.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was suspecting that this is the same issue. I was curious if anybody has ran into something similar where they were able to by pass this two way bind.

Comment: Actually thank you for making me look at this twice! i updated the moment-picker variable with something different and that did the trick! Thank you again!!